# How to control what your app does after inserting event into a calendar

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

In my android app the user is able to add an event to their calendar which is done using the following code.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startTime.getTimeInMillis());
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis());
        intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, name);
        startActivity(intent);
```

however, after the event is put into the calendar, sometimes it returns to the home page of the app, sometimes it returns to the page in the app where the event is input into the calendar and sometimes it redirects the user to the calendar app. Is there a way to explicitly tell the app where to redirect after inserting an event into the calendar?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you come up with any solution this?